# Using js classes over probs react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, react-redux, jsx

I'm studying react for a hobby and I've a question.

Many people create a function for a component when working with react and it works just fine. They use (probs) to specify each "child" of a component like this:

```
function Foo(probs) {
    // react stuff with those probs
}
```

It works pretty good and all but you know what I would like? Object oriented programming!

So instead of creating functions for each class and specify them in the main function, I create a class for each of my component like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const firstbook = {
  title: "some title",
  autor: "someone",
  img: "some url",
};

function Booklist() {
  return (
    <div>
      {new Book(firstbook)}
    </div>
  );
}

class Book {
  constructor(data) {
    this.title = data.title;
    this.autor = data.autor;
    this.img = data.img;

    return (
      <div className="book">
        <h1>{this.title}</h1>
        <h2>{this.autor}</h2>
        <img src={this.img} alt=""></img>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function render() {
  ReactDOM.render(<Booklist />, document.getElementById("root"));
}
render();
```

The questions is, is that ok? I don't know much of a react and I'm afraid to go to some problems when I process. or can't do this for every single component.
Please help me find out! Sorry for my bad English btw.

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript there is no difference you use class or functional component, as it okay. But for people from Earth it's quite troublesome to face both of this ways to create components. Better to use functional as it more modern. If u haven't heard about ES6, try to abuse it. Anyway good luck in studying!

Comment: functional programming isn't a modern concept at all. But it's more practical; if designed correctly, you end up with reusable components which can be applied for vastly different usecases.